# Stopping certain extensions from being posted into MySQL through form? preg_match_all?

Tags: php

I have done some searching on here and would like to make the user posted links that do get displayed on my site to have an extra layer of security. I found some code on here and modified it, but it doesn't seem to be picking up the words set in my array.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'mysql-connection.php';
    $comment = $_POST[comment];
    $comment = htmlentities($comment);
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
    $bannedwords = array(".exe",".zip");
    $matches = array();
    $matchFound = preg_match_all(
                    "/\b(" . implode($bannedwords,"|") . ")\b/i", 
                    $comment, 
                    $matches
                  );

    if ($matchFound) {
        header("Location: http://mydomain/index.php");
    }
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (postid, post_content, username)
    VALUES ('', '$comment', '$username')");
    header("Location: http://mydomain.org/index.php");
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I am grabbing the comment with $_POST[comment]; and then changing it so the if they post html tags it doesn't mess with the layout of the page. We then make it so the $comment won't cause any mysql damage.

Next is where I am encountering the issue. $bannedwords should basically be setting non case sensative mixtures of each word within the array in this case .exe .eXe .Exe and so fourth.

I'm stuck because it still posts fine instead of refreshing the page.

Comment: What you are doing here is pretty much pointless. The file extension of a URL has absolutely no bearing on the type of content that you will receive from it. For the record, the problem is probably that you didn't escape the `.` in the file extensions in the array, so they are being treated as a PCRE any character match. To fix this you can `implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $bannedwords))`

Comment: This was absolutely the issue. I'm not really worried too much on the links and what they do after they are off the server, I just didn't want to be responsible for them posting links on my site directly to the files themselves. So thanks for your input.